# What is the proper way to handle connections betweeen client/server in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

In socket programming, specifically TCP Sockets, if you have two programs (client and server) where the client is a loop that keeps taking the user's input then does a write stream while the server repeatedly listens by using TCPListen's AcceptTCPClient method (.NET Socket classes). On the client side program, at the end of each iteration, do you close the the connection with the server then re-instantiate the TCPClient class at the beginning of the next iteration?

I assume this because the server wants close connection with (dequeue your TCPClient socket?) in order to serve the waiting connections. However, I don't think it is computationally proper to re-instantiate the TCPClient class every time (client side). I tried to use the Connect and Close methods, but they yield run-time errors.

Comment: There is no reason for the server to close connections to serve others. Take a look at asynchronous sockets and you'll be all set. Currently you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I think you are right, the listening method is blocking which implies that the current connection must be closed?. I think I should complete go through all the concepts to gain a whole perspective. Thank you.

Comment: 'the listening method is blocking which implies that the current connection must be closed' Where do you get that idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly *could* make all your connections short lived, but you certainly don't *need* to.

The `Accept` loop is really there so multiple clients can connect. There is nothing that says you can't just leave your connection open until you are actually done.

As far as re-instantiating goes, you are taking a far bigger hit by re-establishing the TCP socket, so I wouldn't worry about the object construction too much.

Comment: The TCPListen's AccceptTCPClient returns a TCPClient instance with the current accepted client and will replace it with the previous one. So the previous client will receive a run-time error when resending again because the connection will be closed, which forces you to reconnect again (didn't work when using client.Connect()) and gives you only one option which is to re-instantiate the client to connect to the server again.

Comment: @Furified Not if you do it right. Whatever call you are making that does that is the *wrong* one. Now, if *you* did something silly like overwriting your old variable, thats your problem :)

Comment: It was the way presented in the book I am using (TCP/IP Programming using Csharp).

Comment: @Furified Unfortunately I cannot speak to the accuracy of your book. That said, I've done this several times and *never* had the experience you are describing.

Comment: Can you suggest several references to explain exactly what is going on under the hood. Not too lower level though. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes, @BradleyDotNET, be a good boy and fetch *several* references.  There's a good chap.

Comment: @SamAxe Why is the mockery?

Comment: AcceptTCPClient creates a new tcpclient for a new client connection that is totally unaware of the previous one. You probably did not read the book very well.

Comment: At the end (Ch5), there is an explanation of everthing that is going on, it's called Under the Hood, which explains what is specifically going on and such as the Data structures used and shows the issues rising from application programs and such, I should have jumped to this chapter from the start. Thanks.